# Is the Total Amount of Induced Charge in a Conductor Inside a Uniform Field Determined by Geometry Only?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, charge

When a conductor is placed inside a uniform field, does the amount of induced charge only depend on the geometry of the object? For example, if this were true, then the amount of induced charge inside an ellipsoid in the said field would be the same, regardless of its orientation, and we could then justify the stability of the ellipsoid on its major axis, by noticing that the dipole moment is greater when it lies on its longest axis.

Although this idea of "the total amount of charge" is quite vague and perhaps even misleading, I would like to think of this as the absolute value of the mirror charges related to the induced charges in the conductor.

[image: Conducting sphere inside electric field]

For now, I do not have a definite answer regarding this question.

Comment: The magnitude of the field will be important in terms of the amount of charge that is moved. The geometry of the object will impact the distribution of the charge. The composition of the object, metal or dielectric will be important as well.

Answer (score 0):

A conducting ellipsoid can be treated using elliptical coordinates, but it gets complicated.  A simple, if extreme, case is the difference between a conducting needle and a disk, each with its axis aligned with an electric field, $\bf E_0$.  The needle will have a small charge at its ends, and the disk will have a large charge on his surfaces. The disk would have a larger surface charge density.  The dipole moment of either would depend on the dimensions.  The dipole moments would be greatest when they are aligned with the field.